# Laravel Queue not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue

I used laravel 5 and Queue. try this

```
$job = (new InstallTheme())->onQueue('install_theme')->delay(20);
            dispatch($job);
```

not work

```
$job = (new InstallTheme())->delay(20);
        dispatch($job);
```

work

Why the first option does not work?

upd
laravel work only if fuild "queue" in table 'jobs' = default

how to fix this?

i think setting queue.php ?

```
'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],
```

Comment: How are you listening for jobs? Are you using supervisor?

Comment: is this version 5.0?

Comment: use php artisan queue:listen
and laravel 5.5

Comment: Does this work? `dispatch(new InstallTheme())->onQueue('install_theme')->delay(20);`

Comment: laravel work only if fuild "queue" in table 'jobs' = default. 



I think need setting queue.php 


'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I recall

```
$job = (new InstallTheme())->onQueue('install_theme')->delay(20);
            dispatch($job);
```

puts the job into the `install_theme` queue while your other code puts it into the default queue. Please try to run the queue worker with this parameters.

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=install_theme
```

This should specifically process the job from this queue.